# On form submittal, a tick kills the app. But only in production

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

A client just recently moved an application through the stages to production.  I set up a testing environment on an "out-of-the-box" LAMP server, and can submit a form with a tick in the textarea.

But in production the exact same code dies, but doesn't even execute the "or die();"

I mysql_real_escape_string the input, which is why it works in my test environment.

Why wouldn't this work on the "same" setup?

Comment: The client said that the error log was still empty after being purged this morning.

Comment: I suggest comparing the outputs of a local and a remote phpinfo() to see if it's a PHP configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a php.ini issue, check your magic quotes options.